# rename multiple files with script

Tags: batch-file, windows-console

I found this script on here and modified it.  It works only for 1 file at a time not multiple files.  How can I get this script to rename multiple files in the directory specified?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set X=64
set Y=4
set FOLDER_PATH=c:\temp\renamefiles\files
pushd %FOLDER_PATH%
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
  set "filename=%%~nf"
  set "filename=!filename:~%X%,-%Y%!"
  ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
popd
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - the script renames ALL files in the FOLDER_PATH (but not a file with the script's name - weird!). And that without regard whether the filename contains the letter to be substituted or not. I would write a new script from scratch which first filters files to be renamed and then renames only those.

Comment: Have you tried PowerShell? `gci "c:\temp\renamefiles\files\" | ren {$_.Name.SubString(64, $_.Name.Length-60)}`

Comment: Turns out the script works fine.  I wasn't paying attention to the 2 files I put in the folder to test with, they ended up having the same name.  My bad.  However, I really like that powershell script, boom!  Now I have 2 different ways to rename files!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean, but this is working for me:

```
ren "path\to\your\folder\*.*" "foo.*"
```

If you execute this command, every file, no matter if there are .txt, .png, .foo, .bar,.. files.

Every file in that folder will get renamed to "foo".
But if there are for example four .png files, there will be only one .png file falled foo.png, because the others can't rename when there is other files with the exactly same name already there.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand these but I think you're renaming every files with the same name and that is illegal (for example you can't have a file.txt on a directory that already has file.txt)
But I am not sure if that is really the case since I don't understand the given code.

Comment: Your answer just restates a conclusion that was already reached years ago.  This answer doesn't add any new information or solutions, so there isn't any value for the community in it.